# How to filter a query by multiple meta keys and order by other meta keys

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order

I'm trying to query posts using `WP_Query` and `meta_query` parameters:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'produkty',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'produkt_aktywny',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'produkt_dostepnosc',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What should I add to order the results by two other meta keys (`'produkt_kategoria'` and `'produkt_cena'`)?